# Laravel database query fail?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database set-up like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmnfv.jpg

My code is this

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Apartment;
use Auth;
use App\Rate;
use Braintree;
use App\Sponsorship;
use App\Payment;
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function index(Sponsorship $sponsorship)
{
     //definisco la data di scadenza con CARBON
      $current_timestamp = Carbon::now('Europe/Rome')->toDateTimeString();

     //recupero la sponsorizzazione in database più recente, dell'appartamento in oggetto
      $apartment = Apartment::all()->where("id","=", $sponsorship->apartment_id)->where("expiry_date", ">", $current_timestamp);

dd($apartment);
```

What i want to do is show only the apartments where Apartment Id is equal to apartment_id in sponsorship table, and also where the sponsorship isn't expired.

I get an empty array as a result.

I think I'm building the query wrong: any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you call for `all()` the query is run and returns all results in DB.

use `get()` after `where()` to get the results wanted

```php
$apartment = Apartment::where("id","=", $sponsorship->apartment_id)->where("expiry_date", ">", $current_timestamp)->get();
```

if you want something working, try this

```php
if ($sponsorship && $sponsorship->expiry_date > $current_timestamp ) {
    $apartment = Apartment::find($sponsorship->apartment_id);
} else {
    //no valid sponsorship
    $apartment = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your solution but i get an SQLSTATE ERROR: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'expiry_date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `apartments` where `id` is null and `expiry_date` > 2020-09-09 13:37:44)

Comment: @Cronos90 but that is not related to your question you need to fix your query yourself, the answer is just a HOW TO do it. plus why is `$sponsorship->apartment_id` null, and of you get apartment by id, why are you filtering by date ? and expiry date is part of the sponsorship not the apartment

Answer (score 0):

Here is something maybe you want, you should call the 'get()' method instead of 'all()' at the last of the method Channing, and also use the relationship for getting this kind of result,  Check the below code, there are controller method and model method Hopefully, it will help you.

#Controller Method

```
 public function index(Sponsorship $sponsorship)
  {
       $current_timestamp = Carbon::now('Europe/Rome')->toDateTimeString();
       $apartment = Apartment::with('sponsorship')
         ->whereHas('sponsorship',function($query)use($sponsorship,$current_timestamp) {
             $query->where('id',$sponsorship->id)
             ->where('expiry_date','>',$current_timestamp);
         })->get();

    dd($apartment);
  }
```

#Model Method for relationship

## Apartment Model

```
public function sponsorship()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Sponsorship', 'apartment_id', 'id');
}
```

Here I assume that your models have 'Has one relationship', which means an
Apartment does not have more than one Sponsorship.